# Flyway and gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, flyway, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm migrating from Gradle to Gradle Kotlin DSL, and I have a question.
Have

```
flyway {
    url = System.getenv ('DB_URL')
    user = System.getenv ('DB_USER')
    password = System.getenv ('DB_PASSWORD')
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    locations = ["filesystem: resources / db / migration"]
}
```

In Gradle.

How would you look in Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code in the block is almost exactly the same in Kotlin as in Groovy, with two exceptions for what you have above:

- Use double-quotes instead of single-quotes for the strings.
- Use `arrayOf` instead of `[...]` for the array for the `locations` property.

In other words it would look as follows:

```
flyway {
    url = System.getenv("DB_URL")
    user = System.getenv("DB_USER")
    password = System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    locations = arrayOf("filesystem: resources / db / migration")
}
```

Bear in mind that for the build file to understand the `flyway` function (and for the IDE to give you intellisense for what options are available in the block, etc.) you need to apply the Flyway plugin using the [Gradle Plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block), as follows at the top of your `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "5.2.4"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, "flyway {...}" is still unrecognized. EDIT: Had to update the 'script context' (whatever this might be). Now it works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
tasks.withType<org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask> {
    url = System.getenv ('DB_URL')
    user = System.getenv ('DB_USER')
    password = System.getenv ('DB_PASSWORD')
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    locations = ["filesystem: resources / db / migration"]
}
```